# Laravel database cache

Tags: mysql, database, caching, laravel

I'm working on an ecommerce website, in each page of this site, there's this header that contains shopping cart information, so each time a page with this header that has shopping cart in it loads, the database gets hit. I wonder if I can use database cache technique to reduce query times? Like if nothing's changed, then do not fetch data from the database unless new product(s) are added into shopping cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, but it sounds like a bad idea and I disencourage it because cache is shared with the whole application and shopping cart information is related to a single user. For this kind of user specific information is better to leverage to cookies or session.

Anyway, here you have. You didn't provide any code sample so I made up something generic. The trick is to add to the cache key something that makes it unique for each user (such the model primary key) and after adding/removing a product to/from the cart clear the cache using the previous cache key.

```
// Code to get current user shopping cart (The one that will be shown in your header)
$cart = Cart::where('user_id', $user_id = Auth::user()->getKey())->remember(60*2, "cartOfUser$user_id")->get();

// Code that adds a product to the cart
Cart:addProduct($product, $qty) and Cache::forget('cartOfUser' . Auth::user()->getKey());
```

My advise is to not over-optimize now. I'm sure the cart database query is not a big deal. Finish your application, polish it, and when everything is working as expected run a profiler to locate bottlenecks and then optimize.

Comment: Yeah, point taken, I agree that cache database query for so many different users is a bad idea.